# make the full circular path, shortest path exercise?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I got this question in an interview and I was not able to solve it.

> You have a circular road, with N number of gas stations. You know the
>   ammount of gas that each station has. You know the ammount of gas you
>   need to GO from one station to the next one. Your car starts with 0
>   gas. The question is: Create an algorithm, to know from which gas
>   station you must start driving to COMPLETE the circular PATH.  It does
>   not specify that you must visit all stations. You can only drive
>   clockwise.

I had to do it in c#

The only code I started is with a GasStation entity

```
class GasStation
  int gasAtStation;
  int gasToMoveToNextStationNeeded;
  string nameOfGasStation;


GasTation wheretoStart(List<GasStation> list)
{

}
```

I did it this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] gasOnStation = {1, 2, 0, 4};
            int[] gasDrivingCostTonNextStation = {1, 1,2, 1};

            FindStartingPoint(gasOnStation, gasDrivingCostTonNextStation);

        }

        static void FindStartingPoint(int[] gasOnStation, int[] gasDrivingCosts)
        {
            // Assume gasOnStation.length == gasDrivingCosts.length
            int n = gasOnStation.Length;
            int[] gasEndValues = new int[n];
            int gasValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                gasEndValues[i] = gasValue;
                gasValue += gasOnStation[i];
                gasValue -= gasDrivingCosts[i];
            }

            if (gasValue < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Instance does not have a solution");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                // Find the minimum in gasEndValues:
                int minI = 0;
                int minEndValue = gasEndValues[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                    if (gasEndValues[i] < minEndValue)
                    {
                        minI = i;
                        minEndValue = gasEndValues[i];
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Start at station: " + minI);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I think homeworks should help you to internalize something what you have learned

Comment: For future reference, edit the new information into your existing question. I closed the old question as a duplicate of this one, and then deleted it.

Comment: "*It does not specify that you must visit all stations*". I bet it does not. That wouldn't be a **shortest past** problem if you would have to visit all stations. Actually, that wouldn't be a problem **at all**.

Comment: Can it be assumed that a solution exists? That is, will there always be at least one station you can start from to finish traversing the path?

Comment: The only thing i make out is you would need an array to hold the gas each station has and index represents those points, the circle becomes a straight line for you in the code, Can i complete it by assuming it takes 0 gas for first circle :)

Comment: If the car has to complete the full circular path, where is the "shortest" part of this problem?

Comment: @Otiel, it can not be shortest path problem, because each vortex have two edges. That connection to next and previous edge.

Comment: it does not specify that you must visit all stations. It specifies that you must make the entire circular path. only. And Yes its supposed that a solution exists.  The car starts with 0 Gas. The question is where the card should start? in which station?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I believe you answered the question

Comment: @Vash Indeed you're right. Problem solved then :). The question is not clear (why 3 votes up?), should be closed again.

Comment: then I suppose its not shortest path, so I am totally lost. :) where did you copy the answer I cant see it?

Comment: @Otiel i suppose the 3 votes up are from people who have seen the previous attempt at this question, and want to retribute the OP for the rewriting and formatting effort...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This seems to be debatable question, if we had values for the gas stations or number of stations this could have been attempted else this seems doomed.

Comment: they only said, N number of Gas Stations, You know upfront how much gas is in each station, and how much you need to get to the next one.   I suppose they would like a generic algorithm that solves all scenarios, but a NON-Generic algorithm in which we can define the number of stations will work for me, at least for learning purposes and to try to understand it.!!!

Comment: @George has already provided a solution that in my mind would work, without knowing any specific scenarios. If a specific scenario is solvable, his algorithm would find the solution(s). The question is if there are more assumptions lurking around, or whether it is required to be more optimized?

Comment: Isn't this an NP-Complete problem? Or am I mistaken??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way of solving this is using a brute force method. i.e. try every posibility and throw out ones that don't work.

i.e. Start at each gas station in turn (repeat below for each starting station).

- Have a varible that defines current gas level.
- Loop through each gas station, in a clockwise order.

  1. Fill up your gas (increment gas by gas station amount).
  2. Check you can move to the next station `(gas >= gasToMoveToNextStationNeeded)`

     - If not, this isn't a solution, so move to the next starting location.
     - If so, subtract that amount of gas used, then keep going until you reach the start again.
  3. If you get back to the starting gas station you have an answer.

---

**Edit As per @Vash's answer**,  As an improvement when deciding where to start, discount stations that don't have enough gas themselves to get to the next station and working through starting stations in order of amount of gas (descending).

---

Note, this assumes we visit all gas stations. Will need refinement for skipping gas stations if you need an optimal solution (question doesn't specify this).

Comment: If you save start station, stop station and remaining fuel count every time when step 2 fails, it makes possible skipping some algorithm steps on next iteration and brute force becomes ideal O(n) solution.

Comment: Feel free to edit (or post your own answer), i think i understand what you're getting at, but not enough to work out that actual algorithm. Also, guess this would only apply if you kept the original gas station order (when deciding where to start).

Answer (score 2):

This is optimized case of @George Duckett's answer.

- Choose and remember your start station.
- Loop(1) through stations clockwise.

  - Get a fuel.
  - If you have enough fuel, go to next station, decrease remaining fuel amount, continue loop(1)

If you reached your start station - problem solved.

If on some station you do not have enough fuel to reach next one

- Remember your end station.
- Distance_to_start = 0, fuel_to_start = 0
- Loop(2) from your start station counterclockwise.

  - Add available fuel and distance to next station to your counters
  - If fuel_to_start > distance_to_start, you have some excess fuel. Mark this station as your new start and go to loop(1) again - may be you can go ahead now.
  - Otherwise, continue loop(2)

If you had gone counterclockwise to already visited station - bad luck, there is not enough fuel on stations to go full circle.

Answer (score 1):

The task is really open. As you do a cycle, so the best option is to start from the station that have largest enough fuel amount. This mean that you will be able to tank your car and drive to next nearest station.

When we have a place to start we only have to decide on which gas station we need to stop. For the first run we can stop an every station.

*EDIT.*

Small improvement that came up after discussion with Lasse V. Karlsen.

If the selected first station will not succeed to make the cycle. Then select next one in the same way with smaller* fuel/road proportion.

*Smaller then first selected station proportion.

Comment: I'm not convinced this method of picking the starting gas station works in all cases where there is a solution.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the station with the most fuel has enough for you to get to the next station. The previous station could have less fuel available, but require so little to get to the one with the most that you have more available when you leave the one with the most, than if you started at it.

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen, that why i wrote 'largest enought fuel amount' not most fuel. it about founding the best proportion, of success.

Comment: Example: Station 1 has 100 units of fuel, requires 10 to get to the next. Station 2 has 200 units of fuel, but requires 250 to get to the next station.

Comment: @Lasse, His wording is confusing but he's saying find the largest that satisfies the condition of having enough to get to the next one. "The largest **enough** fuel amount.

Comment: @ George Duckett, neither do I, but i should stand for 90% of cases. It could a fist way to calculate the result, if do not pass then a brutal force can be used.

Comment: In a cycle with 3 stations, station 1 has 100, require 10 to next, station 2 has 150, require 275 to next, station 3 has 50, require 10 to next (which is the first station). If you start at station 1 (which has the most, and you can reach the next station), you won't be able to complete the next leg because you're left with 240 units when trying to leave station 2.

Comment: All you can filter out by looking at 1 station and the amount it has vs. the amount required is which stations can *potentially* be the solution, but you will still need to look at all the qualifying ones.

Comment: Using a single example you can corrupt any theory. I do not claim that this is perfect solution for all cases. You have right that this is not a perfect solution. Im looking forward for you alg. that will solve all cases without checking them all. That was only a idea of concept. When we have an example we adjust our thoughts around it. In that example is clear that you will have to start from station three. So we can add an improve that if the first pick fail try with the second in order. Then we will find solution in two iterations. So it better than starting sequentially.

Comment: If he's asked to come up with an *algorithm* that solves the problem, then obviously he's asked to come up with an algorithm that solves *all* the scenarios, provided there actually is a solution to a given scenario. If that isn't the case then he should just always start at the first station given. Simple solution that would have a chance of 1/N (where N is number of stations) to succeed.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, I understand your point, but algorithm do not stand for 'This logic will find always an answer', but more like 'this logic will always produce the same output for same input'. never then less, i think that we can agree that after improvement, it will find solution also for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Make circular list of stations.
Find any station with positive value of

Excess = (gasAtStation - gasToMoveToNextStationNeeded)

This is current base.

While next station has negative Excess value, add it's gasAtStation and gasToMoveToNextStationNeeded to current base fields, and remove this station from list.

Repeat for all positive stations circularly.

When no more stations to remove:

If one or some non-negative stations remains in list - any of them is suitable as starting point.

Example:

A(-50) B(100) C(-20) D(-90) E(60)   [C->B]

A(-50) B(80) D(-90) E(60)   [D->B]

A(-50) B(-10) E(60)  [A->E]

B(-10) E(10)  [B->E]

E(0)

Answer (score 1):

While trying each start station of course works fine, it takes quadratic time, while there is a simple linear-time algorithm.

Use a magic car that can keep going if the fuel level runs into the negative. Start at an arbitrary station and do a full tour, visiting every station. If you return with less than zero fuel, there is no solution. Otherwise, the best station to start is the one where the fuel level on arrival was lowest.

This works because the fuel levels of all possible tours are identical except for a constant offset.

Answer (score 1):

If we define that a trip from station A to B comprises of the GasAtStation A and TripCost.
Then for each trip we have that TripBalance = GasAtStation-TripCost

The sum of all the trip balances must be greater or equal to zero, otherwise a solution does not exist. The solution consists of having a list with the trip balances for each gas station and iterate through the items keeping a variable for the tripBalance, if the tripBalance becomes negative, then the trip should start at the next gas station, if so, we reset the tripBalance and we keep processing until we check the last entry in the list:

```
public int FindFirstStation(List<int> tripBalances)
{
  if (tripBalances.Sum() < 0) return -1;
  var firstStation = 0;
  var tripBalance = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < tripBalances.Count; i++)
  {
    tripBalance += tripBalances[i];
    if (tripBalance < 0)
    {
      tripBalance = 0;
      firstStation = i + 1; // next station
    }
  }
  return firstStation;
}
```

I tested it using the following code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Example()
{
  var tripBalances = new List<int> { 0, 1, -2, 3 };
  var resolver = new GasStationResolver();
  var indexOfGasStation = resolver.FindFirstStation(tripBalances);
  Assert.AreEqual(3, indexOfGasStation);
}
```

See that the passed values are the ones worked out from the example given at the question header. In this case, the answer is that the last gas station in our list should be the first gas station. Finally, if there is not solution, the method returns -1.

Another example to cover where the stations with higher gas are not the solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Station 1 - Gas: 3   Cost: 4
/// Station 2 - Gas: 10  Cost: 11
/// Station 3 - Gas: 8   Cost: 9
/// Station 4 - Gas: 6   Cost: 3
/// Station 5 - Gas: 4   Cost: 2
/// 
/// Then - Trip Balances are:
/// Station 1 - -1
/// Station 2 - -1
/// Station 3 - -1
/// Station 4 -  3
/// Station 5 -  2
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]    
public void SecondExample()
{
  var tripBalances = new List<int> { -1, -1, -1, 3, 2 };
  var resolver = new GasStationResolver();
  var indexOfGasStation = resolver.FindFirstStation(tripBalances);
  Assert.AreEqual(3, indexOfGasStation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the gas station with the most gas but for when the gas for the next station when added to the tank does not exceed the capacity of the tank.

Comment: There is no information that the tank has an upper limit. Since this is a purely theoretical exercise, I would assume it can hold "enough".

Comment: so starting with the station with the most gas and picking up all the gas along the way should suffice.

Comment: Incorrect answer. Assume you have this path: (10 fuel) - 11 distance - (5 fuel) - 2 distance - (4 fuel) - 2 distance - [loop]. If you start with 10 fuel, you can't go anywhere, you have to start one station ahead.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech, no, that wouldn't work in all cases. The station with most gas may be too far from the next station.

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps?

- Find the gas station with the largest amount of gas
- List all gas stations, and take their fuel value, subtract the cost of driving there
- Drive to the gas station with the highest value
- Repeat until all gas stations are visited

Comment: It's a one-way circular road, so from any given gas station there's only one option, you can't just drive from one to any other.